# Is AppFapric mature for production

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, workflow-foundation, appfabric

We have a lot of WCF services using as a host windows services. And as we are upgrading our servers to windows server 2008 R2 we are planning to migrate some of services under WAS.
Also having already the release of AppFabric it is interesting does AppFabric is mature to be used, so may be we can use it instead of WAS. Is there already someone using in on production.
And what are your impressions, of course maximum objectively :).

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Just want to here is there anyone using AppFabric as already some time passed after its release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppFabric is not released yet but still in RC at the moment. I am not sure of the RC license allows for production usage but I certainly haven't and would not be rushing it. Even though it build on top of IIS/WAS is is a very new product and I would first start with a small set of services to test it.

Comment: Yes I agree, for production it would be risky. Better to run some test services for some period. At least need to play around a little...